# Getting the user owned pages using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the page_id of user owned pages using graph api and fql search .I used $facebook->api('/me/accounts') (Graph API) but its showing an  error

```
 error :[message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the     
 current user.
  [type] => OAuthException
  [code] => 2500 .
```

I have also user fql query but its not working .I have a doubt like what and where should i use access tokes and where should i specify managed permissions .

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966015/facebook-get-list-of-pages-that-a-user-is-admin-of .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to obtain basic permissions to access the user data. There is a ton of info on that including the official documentation. Once you have basic permissions your api call

```
$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
```

should be working

Comment: sir I have browsed alot and could not perfect solutions ...where should i get or define the permissions ..I have defined in the login part is that correct ?$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'manage_pages'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
            )
    );

Comment: Not sure if you copy/pasted the above but it has wrong syntax. $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'manage_pages', redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['baseurl'] ) );

You don't need manage_pages to access the data.